# How long does it take to grow Tagasaste (Tree Lucerne) from seed?

Tags: trees, planting, germination, growth

I am planning to plant a few dozens of Tagasaste (Tree Lucerne) on my section in Southland, New Zealand in August/September this year. I have read a few instructions on how to germinate seeds and start growing them in pots until the plants become half a meter long — when it is time to plant them in their permanent place outside.

However, none of those instructions seem to clearly convey the time that Tagasaste normally takes to grow from seed to half a meter long. When should I start germinating seeds if I am planning to put the plants into permanent soil in early September?

Answer (score 2):

From internet, it seems between 15 days to 4 weeks (to 40 days for the later seeds) to germinate (from seed to first green part emerging). But it seems very difficult to get them to germinate, so there are various methods which effect the time to germinate (cutting seeds, fire, water, etc.).

One to three additional months to get the plant ready to be ready. If it is too early or too late, you can temporarily pot in individual pot, and plant it when it is the right time (according outside weather conditions).

Comment: "_One to three additional months to get the plant ready_" — can you please provide reference, or is that your experience with Tagasaste?

Answer (score 2):

Do not cut your seeds. I have had huge success germinating the seeds with the "old seed method" which is to soak the seeds in 250ml water (preferably water with no chlorine or other chemicals in) plus three drops of 10% vol peroxide and a quarter teaspoon sugar. Soak for three days.

The seeds will swell up. That is the sign that the seed is viable and ready to be planted in soil. I made the mistake of leaving my seedlings in a pot for too long (about 8 months) and the tap root curled up inside the pot. I have transplanted them now and I am waiting to see if they will survive. My next lot of seeds are busy sprouting also in a pot but I will be sure to plant them directly in the soil where I want them to grow when they are about 5cm long this time around.

What I would like to know is how long will they take to go to seed after they are planted in the soil?

Comment: Hi Ayla, this site works differently.  We only want answers in the answer box.  You are welcome to ask your own question separately.